# How convert JavaRDD<Row> to JavaRDD<List<String>>?

Tags: java, list, apache-spark

```
JavaRDD<List<String>> documents = StopWordsRemover.Execute(lemmatizedTwits).toJavaRDD().map(new Function<Row, List<String>>() {
    @Override
    public List<String> call(Row row) throws Exception {
        List<String> document = new LinkedList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i<row.length(); i++){
            document.add(row.get(i).toString());
        }
        return  document;
    }
});
```

I try make it with use this code, but I get WrappedArray

```
[[WrappedArray(happy, holiday, beth, hope, wonderful, christmas, wish, best)], [WrappedArray(light, shin, meeeeeeeee, like, diamond)]]
```

How make it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getList` method:

```
Dataset<Row> lemmas = StopWordsRemover.Execute(lemmatizedTwits).select("lemmas");
JavaRDD<List<String>> documents = lemmas.toJavaRDD().map(row -> row.getList(0));
```

where `lemmas` is the name of the column with lemmatized text. If there is only one column (it looks like this is the case) you can skip `select`. If you know the index of the column you can skip `select` as well and pass index to `getList` but it is error prone.

Your current code iterates over the `Row` not the field you're trying to extract.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with using an excel file :

```
JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile(yourPath);
        
String header = data.first();

JavaRDD<String> dataWithoutHeader = data.filter(line -> !line.equalsIgnoreCase(header) && !line.isEmpty());

JavaRDD<List<String>> dataAsList = dataWithoutHeader.map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(";")));
```

hope this peace of code help you